# Animated SVG spinner uses excessive cpu and gpu

Tags: performance, animation, svg, css-animations, smil

My app uses a [circular progress spinner from the material-ui](https://codesandbox.io/s/wwjyz58948) package and I noticed cpu spikes whenever it was used. I couldn't really tell why it consumed so much GPU and CPU, so I set out to find another spinner I had used earlier (the example code below), as I assumed that was performing better. I was wrong: it suffered from the same issue.

Hence, I wonder how I can improve the performance of SVG spinners such as this one, as it seems to be a problem of a more general nature. This SVG uses SMIL animations, but as the [linked demo shows](https://codesandbox.io/s/wwjyz58948) it also happens using CSS animations (keyframes).

I have tried tricks, such as enabling a separate compositing layer using `translateZ` and similar stuff, but I couldn't tell any difference in the cpu usage.

[image: High GPU and CPU usage]

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" id="spinner">

        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" stroke="rgba(43,43,43,0.3)" fill="none" stroke-width="10" stroke-linecap="round"/>
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round">
            <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" from="0" to="502"/>
            <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" values="150.6 100.4;1 250;150.6 100.4"/>
        </circle>
        
</svg>
```

Comment: This is still a problem. My GPU goes to 40% when spinning a simple SVG even if it's only sized to 50x50 pixels. Frankly it's sort of pathetic and since mine is also a loader graphic it just serves to ramp up my CPU fan every time I refresh the page.

Answer (score 2):

CSS animations `transform: rotate()` and `opacity` should yield the highest performance and lowest CPU usage.  I think your SVG animation could be achieved by restructuring and rewriting with 3+ static DOM layers that rotate around the center and time the fading in/out to achieve a similar effect.  I don't know SVG well-enough to exemplify, but static SVG/raster images yield a computationally low alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I am not sure I understand what `opacity` has to do with this. There is no fading in-out. The dynamic length of the stroke is what seems to spike the CPU. That is a lot of computation no matter what. A simple rotate wouldn't suffice here, since the stroke length differs throughout the animation. If you have a raster example using canvas or similar I'd love to see.

Comment: Unfortunately, the CSS animation would be a hack that visually simulates the SVG animation with a performance tradeoff, and the dynamic stroke length would be lost.